# Moving Microsoft Terminal Services from one server to another

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services

What is the easiest way to move all settings and users' profiles from one terminal server to another one? Both on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 3):

The "most supported" way would be to transition all the users to Terminal Services roaming user profiles, let them logon and logoff of the old server computer to cause their profiles to be copied up to the roaming share. Things will work "as normal" on the new server computer, then.

(I am assuming that the users are logging-on with domain accounts. If they're using local accounts on the server computer(s) then this is a whole different ballgame...)